# How can I use "pythoncom" with python 3.6 64bits

Tags: python-3.x, win32com, pythoncom

I have to use "pythoncom" to receive the variable from another application.
I have downloaded "pywin32" from this website.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/?

Because my NB is win10 64bit and I use python 3.6 64bits to run my script,I want run "pythoncom" in python3.6 64bits too.
However , it seems like "pythoncom" only available in python 32bits?!

Is there anyway that I could run "pythoncom" in python 3.6 64bits ?